# Can't shred XML data with cross apply

Tags: xml, t-sql, xpath

Given this XML fragment (VINs are obviously bogus)

```
<VehicleFeed>
  <Vehicle>
    <VIN>1234</VIN>
    <Equipment>
      <EquipmentDesc>1.1</EquipmentDesc>
      <EquipmentDesc>1.2</EquipmentDesc>
      <EquipmentDesc>1.3</EquipmentDesc>
    </Equipment>
  </Vehicle>
  <Vehicle>
    <VIN>2345</VIN>
    <Equipment>
      <EquipmentDesc>2.1</EquipmentDesc>
      <EquipmentDesc>2.2</EquipmentDesc>
      <EquipmentDesc>2.3</EquipmentDesc>
    </Equipment>
  </Vehicle>
</VehicleFeed>

What I really want is this result set

VIN  EquipmentDesc
---  -------------
1234 1.1
1234 1.2
1234 1.3
2345 2.1
2345 2.2
2345 2.3
```

I have the xml data in a var named @xdata.  The code below is what I thought would work, but it concatenates all of the equipment values into a single column of data, instead of breaking them into rows.

```
select t.c.value('VIN[1]', 'varchar(20)') as VIN
     , t1.c1.value('.', 'varchar(80)') as EquipDesc
from @xdata.nodes('//VehicleFeed/Vehicle') as t(c)
cross apply t.c.nodes('Equipment') as t1(c1)
```

I.e., I am getting

```
VIN  EquipmentDesc
---  -------------
1234 1.11.21.3
2345 2.12.22.3
```

I clearly am doing something wrong, presumably with the cross apply, or the selection of the description data (or both), but I don't know what it is. Looked like this would be simple, but I am not seeing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized the answer later. I just needed to add on more level of cross apply to descend into the EquipmentDesc element -- brain damage, coding Saturday evening.

```
cross apply t1.c1.nodes('EquipmentDesc') as t2(c2)
```

And select the equipment description value using

```
, t2.c2.value('.', 'varchar(80)') as EquipDesc
```

I don't use cross apply too often, easy to forget what it really means when I tweak some existing code. Sorry if I wasted anyone's time.

ADDED

Final Query (relevant portion at least)

```
select t.c.value('VIN[1]', 'varchar(20)') as VIN
     , t2.c2.value('.', 'varchar(80)') as EquipDesc
from @xdata.nodes('//VehicleFeed/Vehicle') as t(c)
cross apply t.c.nodes('Equipment') as t1(c1)
cross apply t1.c1.nodes('EquipmentDesc') as t2(c2)
```

Comment: Please post the complete corrected query. At least correct the amount that you posted in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the same with a shorter statement:

```
select t.c.value('../../VIN[1]', 'varchar(20)') as VIN
     , t.c.value('.', 'varchar(80)') as EquipDesc
from @xdata.nodes('/VehicleFeed/Vehicle/Equipment/EquipmentDesc') as t(c);
```

Comment: Absolutely, were I not using the intermediate level as well.  Though I would not repeat the full xpath on the final line. Thanks for the reminder though, I bet someone else will learn from this. +1